# Querying Two Custom Post Types with OR Not Working

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, query

I'm trying to query two custom post types - I want all `research_article` to return, but only `events` that are in the future. My events are working as expected, but I'm not getting any research_article posts appearing. What's going wrong here?

```
$today = date( 'Y-m-d' );
        $args = array(
            'post_type'   => array('research_article', 'events'),
            'meta_key'    => 'wpcf-date_time',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
            'order'       => 'DESC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(                    // THIS ONE WORKS
                'key' => 'wpcf-date_time',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'DATE',
                ),
                array(
                  'key'      => 'pub_date', // THIS DOESNT WORK
                  'compare'  => 'EXISTS'
                ),
                'relation' => 'OR',
            )
             );
```

Comment: Looks sensible to me. I'd probably try and find the SQL that WordPress is using, e.g. from the Query Monitor plugin, and work out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue seemed to be with my second meta_query array - instead of checking if pub_date EXISTS, I decided to check if wpcf-date-time DOESNT EXIST:

```
$today = date( 'Y-m-d' );
        $args = array(
            'post_type'   => array('research_article', 'events'),
           'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby'     => 'meta_value date',
            'order'       => 'DESC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array( 
                'key' => 'wpcf-date_time',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'DATE',
                ),
                array(
                  'key'      => 'wpcf-date_time',
                  'compare'  => 'NOT EXISTS'
                ),
                'relation' => 'OR',
            )
        );
```